# Weird behaviour getBoundingClientRect() and F5/reload, what's going on?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My excuses for the long code, I stripped and stripped and stripped again. Codepen is by the nature of this question of no use. I made the code completely stand-alone, you can simply cut and paste in into an html file to see the behaviour.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Garden</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>

#page {      
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns:auto;
    grid-template-rows: 3;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "header"
    "map"
    "footer";
}
  
#header {       
    grid-area: header;
    color: white;
    background-color: grey;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;   
    padding: 5px;  
}

#map {   
    grid-area: map;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    border-top: none;
    padding: 5px;
}   

#imagewrapper {    
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    padding: none;
    margin: none;
}

#mapimage { 
    display: inline;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.pin_container {
    
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    cursor: grab;
    padding: 3px;
}

#footer {
    grid-area: footer;
    color: white;
    background-color: grey;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    border-right: none;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;   
    padding: 5px;  
}
</style>
<div id='page'>
    <div id='header'>De Botanische Tuin Kerkrade</div>
    <div id='map' data-id='14'>
        <div id='imagewrapper'>
            <img id='mapimage' src='https://i.ibb.co/cQF07s8/map-g3-v1.png'>
            <div id='b27' class='pin_container' style='left:479px; top:792px;' data-img='map_g3_b27_v0.png'>Hubertus Borders</div>
            <div id='b22' class='pin_container' style='left:385px; top:568px;' data-img='map_g3_b22_v0.png'>De Oude Tuin</div>
            <div id='b9' class='pin_container' style='left:400px; top:400px;' data-img='map_g3_b9_v0.png'>De Thematuin</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id='footer'><span class='nav_current'>De Botanische Tuin Kerkrade</span></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var map  = document.getElementById('imagewrapper').getBoundingClientRect();
    var pins = document.querySelectorAll('.pin_container');
    var pin;
    var div;
    var loc_x;
    var loc_y;

    for ( var i = 0; i < pins.length; i++ ) { 
        
        pin    = pins[i];
        div    = pin.getBoundingClientRect();
     
        console.log( pin.textContent+"("+pin.id+") - imagewrapper.width="+map.width+", pin_container.width="+div.width );
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyway, I am using js to center the divs with class 'pin_container' on 'imagewrapper'. The size of the imagewrapper is determined by the image it contains, which is set to 100%, so I can easily scale it when the viewport gets smaller than the map.
If I load the page I get this logged to the console, which is fine (the blue line in the map is 100px wide):

```
Hubertus Borders(b27) - imagewrapper.width=707, pin_container.width=123.33
De Oude Tuin(b22) - imagewrapper.width=707, pin_container.width=100.96
De Thematuin(b9) - imagewrapper.width=707, pin_container.width=101.96
```

However, if I refresh the page I get this:

```
Hubertus Borders(b27) - imagewrapper.width=190.93333435058594, pin_container.width=68.66
De Oude Tuin(b22) - imagewrapper.width=190.93333435058594, pin_container.width=44.64
De Thematuin(b9) - imagewrapper.width=190.93333435058594, pin_container.width=79.31
```

As you can see the width of both the map and the pins is bollocks now.
Before I stripped this code to the bone I got yet different results if I used ctrl+f5. I can't seem to find what bit of code caused this behaviour, unfortunately.
I checked with Chrome, Firefox standard and developer. The two foxes produce the behaviour described above, Chrome gives me consistently the wrong output, no mater if I d a fresh load or something with F5.

Mind that the resulting rendering is what I would expect of the proper output, no matter what browser or action I use. However, it messes up the centering script that uses getBoundingClientRect().

What's happening here?

Comment: I'm unable reproduce the issue on my end, but something tells me the issue is the code executed before image was fully loaded.

Comment: That's what my first thought was as well, but there's nothing peculiar in de image tag, the image size isn't that huge, and I test it locally with all files on an ssd. So if this setup doesn't load an image fast enough for this script, what does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not the image loaded late or at least it triggers it indirectly.

to reproduce simply run the loop in the provided code a second time in the console.

---

**This is more of an explanation than an answer.**

We're dealing with absolutely positioned elements, absolutely positioned have no dimensions they're reliant on their content, in this case it's text, Text is unpredictable.

When applied positioning a positioned element using the four properties, It will stop moving when it reaches one of edge, and start shrinking rather than moving until it hits the limit which is the longest word.

And that is what's happening here, before the image loads the parent's width is smaller, the elements are positioned beyond the left edge so they shrink and have a certain width value, after the image loads the width of the parent grows, and the elements width changes according.

A solution would be to define a width/height to your positioned elements or maybe `white-space:nowrap`

i'm not sure how your app is going to scale so I can't give a permanent solution, defining a width/height may not be desirable

Comment: I understand what you are getting at, but why does this happen when I hit F5, but not when the page loads from a bookmark or link? I have almost the same setup for placing the pins, but in that case the image is added as a background to the imagewrapper div (as I don't need to resize the map). Not a problem in sight when I use the same js function to center the pins.
It seems that making the maps resizable is giving me many hurts. :(

Comment: I have no idea, I can't reproduce it the same way you do. So there's something different about your setup, I would assume caching issue but even disabling the cache give the same results

Comment: Weird, weird, weird. It was indeed the loading that caused the problems. I put a 1ms delay on the code, and then it worked, unless I forced a cache refresh. In the end I simply added the width of the map in px to the image tag, which solved everything. Now I wonder why the image still resizes when the viewport gets smaller than the image, but that's another question. Thanks for helping me forward, @Zohir Salak!

Comment: Adding a delay to the code is basically the same thing as refreshing or running the code a second time, You might as well wait for the image to load then run the code which would probably be a fitting solution

Comment: @ZohirSalak First you say image loaded late is not the cause, but than you say it's caused  because image is not yet loaded, hens the parent box has different size until it's loaded. Which one is it than?

Comment: I don't think you've understand the explanation fully, the image loading late triggers width change in the parent, IT's not the problem its just a trigger, if there was no image or the image was smaller than the starting width value of the parent, we won't be talking about it, I say this to clear things out that the image isn't the source of the problem it's just a side effect many things can influence the width of an element.